# What is the music playing in episode 14, when Gowther was talking about the cycles in the cave?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I'm looking for a piece of music in *Seven Deadly Sins* that plays at 5:15 of episode 14, when Gowther explains about the life cycle to the armor beast.

Answer (score 2):

The track is called **PT-16: Taizai** and is from **The Seven Deadly Sins Original Soundtrack 2**.

It is composed by Hiroyuki Sawano.

The track can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_D-Ob908LU

Note that the part that appears in episode 14 starts at around 1:06 on that track.

Comment: I think the track is titled "PT-9: Zai" or "PT-9: Tsumi", not "PT-16: Taizai" (judging from [the album booklet](http://vgmdb.net/db/covers.php?do=view&cover=224437)). Album on VGMDB: http://vgmdb.net/album/50415

Comment: I believe that PT-9 is a different track, PT-16 is track 23 in that album, and I am sure that it is the same as the track used in the mentioned episode.

Comment: My mistake; I think I confused the track number for the number in the title or something. Good answer!